# Magento back end bug

Tags: magento2, bug

Please how do I resolve this bug

"Exception #0 (LogicException): Could not create an acl object: Invalid Document
Element 'resource': The attribute 'title' is required but missing.
Line: 12"

Answer (score 0):

From the exception, it seems you've invalid xml in acl.xml file. `Title` is missing. See below code for reference where `title` is added in `resource`. :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Vendor_Module::some_id" title="Some Title" sortOrder="51">
                    <resource id="Vendor_Module::other_id" title="Something" sortOrder="10">
                        <resource id="Vendor_Module::save" title="Something" translate="title" sortOrder="10" />
                        <resource id="Vendor_Module::delete" title="Something" translate="title" sortOrder="20" />
                    </resource>
                </resource>
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="Vendor_Module::bar_config" title="Something" translate="title"/>
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```